# how to typecast the value of gridviewrow.cells[i] value into int32?

Tags: c#, casting

facing problem while trying to typecast the value of of gridviewrow.cells value into int32 using C#.net.Please consider the following coding.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("studentid",typeof(Int32)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)));
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   DataRow dr;
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkgridselect");
   if ( cb.Checked)
   {
       //Error occurs in the following line when i try to typecast
       dr["studentid"] =Convert.ToInt32( row.Cells[1]);
       dr["Name"] = row.Cells[2];
       dt.Rows.Add(dr);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code and explain how it is failing.

Comment: Maybe you haven't got an Int32 in one of the cells!

Comment: Shouldn't you convert the first cell, the one with index 0? You're actually converting the second column to int, as far as i can tell from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some code would help, but I'm going to take a stab and say to try this:

```
int myVal = Int32.Parse(GridViewRow.Cells[i].Text);
```

Comment: thank you.... your code works... but why it doesnt work when i use ToString() instead of Text?

Comment: @Prem - `Text` is a property of the GridViewCell type that gives you the value of the text displayed in the cell. Calling the `ToString()` method is different; this method is inherited from `Object`. If the class has not overriden this method, the default behaviour is to return the full name of the class, so in this case you'd get something like `System.Web.UI.GridViewCell`, and some version information.

Answer (score 2):

Just a stab in the dark without more info.  But try:

```
int myValue;
if (!int.TryParse(myGridViewRow.Cells[i].Text, out myValue)
 //do something, your value is not an int
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int result;

result = int.Parse(value);

// OR

result = Convert.Int32(value);
```

Comment: Should be `Convert.ToInt32(value)`

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewCell has a Value property.

```
....
dr["studentid"] = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
....
```